# Is a foreign equity holder liable for business debt?

Tags: united-states, india, debt, equity

I'm an Indian citizen residing in India. **If I get 20% equity in a US company, am I responsible for the company's debts (current and future debts)?**

Note that this is a **sweat equity** (no money invested). I'm getting this because of my contribution in product development.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually no.

https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/personally-liable-business-bebts-business-bankruptcy.html

> A corporation is an incorporated entity designed to limit the liability of its owners (called shareholders). **Generally**, shareholders are **not personally liable for the debts of the corporation**. Creditors can only collect on their debts by going after the assets of the corporation.
>
> Shareholders will usually only be on the hook **if they cosigned or personally guaranteed the corporation’s debts**. However, shareholders may also be held liable **if a creditor can prove corporate formalities weren’t followed**, shareholders **commingled personal, and business funds** or the corporation was just a shell designed to shield liability. This is called piercing the corporate veil.